# is the past continuous with a duration better than the past perfect continuous in that case?

Tags: past-tense, past-continuous

> I was looking for him for 8 hours when I have found him
>
> I had been looking  for him for 8 hours when I have found him

Are both sentences equivalent in meaning? I think the second one stress the wait but I think the first one is better as the events are in order there is no need for past perfect

Answer (score 2):

Since you include *duration* before another action and the first action stopped (the speaker definitely stopped looking for), you need Past Perfect Continuous + Past indefinite (not Present Perfect):

> I had been looking for him for 8 hours when I found him.

https://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/pastperfectcontinuous.html

Comment: But it is not possible to use the present perfect for find if I  have just found the person I was looking for

Comment: I think you can combine _Present_ Perfect Continuous (not Past PC, since the event of finding would go to the past) with the Present Perfect: _I've (just) found the person I **have** been looking for 8 hours._